# General formula for the coordinates of points in an isosceles triangle

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I have the following isosceles triangle

[image: Triangle]

If I know the coordinates of points A and B, and the length of the line CC', how can I determine the coordinates of points C and C'? Point A bisects CC'.

(image stolen from [Finding coordinates for 3rd point in isosceles right triangle, knowing 2 other points and lengths of sides](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470673/finding-coordinates-for-3rd-point-in-isosceles-right-triangle-knowing-2-other-p))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not necessitate trigonometry:

Let $r = $ distance AC.

The solution is given by

$$\tag{1}\vec{AC}=r\vec{v} \ \ \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ \ \ C=A+r\vec{v},$$

where $\vec{v}$ is a unit (length 1) vector orthogonal to $\vec{AB}$.

Let $n=\sqrt{(x_B-x_A)^2+(y_B-y_A)^2}$ be the norm of $\vec{AB}$.

Expressing (1) with coordinates (using the fact that vector $\binom{-b}{a}$ is directly orthogonal to  $\binom{a}{b}$):

$$\binom{x_C}{y_C}=\binom{x_A-\tfrac{r}{n}(y_B-y_A)}{y_A+\tfrac{r}{n}(x_B-x_A)},$$

and, in a symmetrical way:

$$\binom{x_{C'}}{y_{C'}}=\binom{x_A+\tfrac{r}{n}(y_B-y_A)}{y_A-\tfrac{r}{n}(x_B-x_A)}.$$

Comment: Thanks, how would this go with vertical/horizontal situations where the slope of the vertical is undefined? It's not likely, but it is possible that my AB line could be perfectly horizontal or perfectly vertical.

Comment: It will work the same way !

Comment: OK cool. thanks. I had some issues when it came to converting this to programming code around division by zero problems. But this was the closest answer here to what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get parametric coordinates of a point $(x,y)$ at $r$ distance from a fixed point $(x_1,y_1)$ on a line with inclination from positive $x$-axis $\theta$

$$x=x_1+r \cos \theta~ ;~ y=y_1+r \cos \theta$$

You can get $\theta$ since CC' is perpendicular to $AB$ therefore $m_{AB} \cdot m_{CC'} =-1$ and you know $r = \dfrac{CC'}{2}$

Hence, coordinates of C and C' will be : $(x_1\pm r \cos \theta,y_1 \pm r \cos \theta)$

You may proceed now.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that is a good start. Just to clarify for me, would the coordinates of C be (x1+rcosθ,y1+rcosθ) and C' be (x1-rcosθ,y1-rcosθ) or have I missed something? I'm not sure of how to deal with multiple coordinates, each of which has a ±.

Comment: Depends where are your axis.Dirst calculate the points with all given data, then for finding coordinates of any of C or C' ,compare it with coordinates of A. You'll easily be able to compare, for example, the height( y coordinate) from x-axis and once you get one coordinate, every thing is resolved.

Comment: It is not necessary to involve trigonometry.

Comment: @JeanMarie It's okay, but that's my way of solving.

Comment: Solutions without trigonometry are often preferable for computer implementation Unless being very cautious with angles, for example by taking atan2 instead of atan or asin. ..